# SQL / PROGRESS Blank in place of NULL Date

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to replace a NULL date with a blank. I end up with invalid date string. Ive Tried COALESCE, ISNULL, IFNULL, CASE STATEMENTS and nothing seems to work. I am querying a LINKED PROGRESS ODBC connection and using

```
declare @Data varchar(max)              
set @Data= N'               
SELECT MyCode
FROM TABLE
'               
exec (@Data  ) AT PROGRESS;
```

Ive done this many times before, I can do ISNULL, COALESCE etc just fine on all my other fields, but not the case with this Date field. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There is no such thing as a blank date.  You have to convert the date to a string and use `coalesce()` on that.  What is Progress?

Comment: https://www.progress.com/openedge

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are accessing a Progress database.
The Progress unknown value ? is what SQL calls NULL.
Date fields can only contain valid dates or (if the field is not mandatory) the unknown value ?. Unlike other data types, unknown values are sometimes displayed as blanks instead of ?, for example when displayed as GUI widgets.
There are no actual *blank dates* in Progress.

Unfortunately I don't know enough SQL to tell exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I had to  make my query an open query and in the outer select do ISNULL(datefield,'')

Comment: If this was actually the solution to your problem, you could accept this answer and let us know. Otherwise, it would be more helpful to copy this and paste it into a comment applicable to the content you were replying to.